# Is there a way to list S3 objects by last modified using airflow?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow

Code below so far

```
t1 = S3ListOperator(
    task_id='list_s3_files',
    bucket='mybucket',
    prefix='v01/{{ds}}/',
    delimiter='/'
)
```

will then copy the latest file across using [`S3CopyObjectOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/s3_copy_object_operator/index.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not a particular "Airflow way", but you could do this with a `PythonOperator`:

```py
all_objects = boto3.resource('s3').bucket(your_bucket_name).objects.iterator()
sorted_objs = sorted(all_objects, key=lambda o: o.last_modified)
latest_file = sorted_objs[-1]
```

Though it's not an "industrial solution", as it requires pulling all the files just to sort them. S3 doesn't support "querying" like that.

If you have a predictable way to segment the files (e.g per-day, per-hour), it wouldn't be that bad though.