# Listing objects in S3 with suffix using boto3

Tags: python, boto3

```
def get_latest_file_movement(**kwargs):
    get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s'))
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket',Prefix='prefix')['Contents']
    last_added = [obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified, reverse=True)][0]
    return last_added
```

Above code gets me the latest file however i only want the files ending with 'csv'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if they end with `.csv`:

```
def get_latest_file_movement(**kwargs):
    get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s'))
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket',Prefix='prefix')['Contents']

    last_added = [obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified, reverse=True) if obj['Key'].endswith('.csv')][0]

    return last_added
```

Comment: yeah i wanted the latest file ending with '.csv', sorry if that wasnt clear in the question

Comment: Note that this will only consider the first 1000 objects in a bucket, which may or may not matter for the given use case.

Answer (score 5):

#### Filter by suffix

If the S3 object's key is a *filename*, the *suffix* for your objects is a filename-extension (like `.csv`).

So filter the objects by key ending with `.csv`.

Use [`filter(predicate, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) operation with predicate as lambda testing for [`str.endswith(suffix)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket',Prefix='prefix')['Contents']

csvs = filter(lambda obj: obj['Key'].endswith('.csv'), objs)  # csv only 
csvs.sort(key=lambda obj: obj['LastModified'], reverse=True)  # last first, sort by modified-timestamp descending

return csvs[0]
```

Note: **To get the last-modified only**

This solution alternates the sort direction using `reverse=True` (descending) to pick the first which will be the last modified.
You can also `sort` default (ascending) and pick the last with `[-1]` as [answered by Kache in your preceding question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70764296/5730279).

#### Simplification

From the [boto3 `list_objects_v2`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) docs about the response structure:

> **Contents** (list)
> ...
> **LastModified** (datetime) -- Creation date of the object.

Boto3 returns a *datetime* object for `LastModified`. See also [Getting S3 objects' last modified datetimes with boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679344/getting-s3-objects-last-modified-datetimes-with-boto).

So why do we need additional steps to format it as string and then convert to int: `int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s'))` ?

Python can also sort the *datetime* directly.

#### Limitation warning

S3's API operation and its corresponding Boto3 method [`list_objects_v2`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/list_objects_v2.html) limit the result set to one thousand objects:

> Returns some or all (up to 1,000) of the objects in a bucket with each request.

So, for buckets with many homonymous objects, even after applying the prefix-filter, your result can be implicitly truncated.

Comment: I like this answer, but you have obj and the lambda function swapped in the filter function. Filter function requires the first parameter to be the function that returns True/False and the second parameter to be the collection.

Comment: @Danny, thanks for spotting this. You always have to pay attention when using built-ins `filter` and `sorted` (the order of parameters is different). That's why I prefer [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) among others (modify in place, readability, etc.).

Comment: Does not scale past 1000 objects under `prefix`.

Comment: @IllyaMoskvin, thanks for the scalability hint. I added this as "Limitation warning".

Comment: I think the answer should be modified to:

csvs = list(filter(lambda obj: obj['Key'].endswith('.csv'), objs))

Comment: @HowardS, Depends on the Python version. In Python2 the filter-function returns a list directly. In Python3 however, the [filter-function returns a filter-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174276/why-does-foo-filter-return-a-filter-object-not-a-list) as _iterator_ which should be [converted to a list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html?highlight=filter#to3fixer-filter) before invoking `sort`.